# How can i unregister document.fire event

Tags: prototypejs

I want to unregister a document.fire (prototype) event. How can i do that? it seems Event.stopObserving working only for the events binded using event.observe

Comment: Your question is confusing. Events are not registered with `fire`, they are triggered with `fire`. Since this is a programming site please post some code to show what it is you are doing.

Comment: I mean if you register document.observe then how to unregister that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unregister from `document.observe` use [`document.stopObserving`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/document/stopObserving/).